# Replacing text in a string with hyphens

Tags: c++, string, getline

I am trying to write a program that simulates a game of Hangman.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "assn.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
     clearScreen();
     cout << "Enter a  word or phrase: ";
     string phrase;
     std::getline(std::cin, phrase);
     cout << endl << "Your phrase: " << phrase << endl;
     cout << endl;
}
```

Currently I can get the input string and retain the spaces, but I want to create another string where all the letters are replaced with hyphens and the spaces are preserved. I've tried looking it up and couldn't find out how to do it.

Comment: C++ have many nice [algorithms in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example one to [replace values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) (or [replace while copying](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace_copy)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using `algorithm`'s `replace_if`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string input{"This is a test"};
    string censored{input};
    replace_if(censored.begin(), censored.end(), ::isalpha, '-');
    cout << censored << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
---- -- - ----
```

The above call to `replace_if` iterates over a container (in this case, a string of characters) and replaces alphabetic ones with dashes, leaving spaces intact.

[Live example](http://rextester.com/JETS32114)

Comment: thank you so much this works really well! Now I just need to figure out how to replace the dashes with the guessed letters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function which returns a hyphened string of your phrase string:

```
std::string replacetohyphen(std::string phrase){
    for(int i=0;i<(int)phrase.length();i++){
    phrase[i]='-';}
    return phrase;}
```

usage: `new_phrase=replacetohyphen(phrase);`

if you want to retain spaces in this new hyphened string too, then a simple if condition inside the `for` loop will do the trick:

```
std::string replacetohyphen(std::string phrase){
    for(int i=0;i<(int)phrase.length();i++){
    if(phrase[i]!=' ')phrase[i]='-';}
    return phrase;}
```

Comment: This will not preserve spaces - though the OP has not specified whether that is required.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of it done manually. I kept your original string so that you can start replacing the letters back as they guess them. I find it is good to do things yourself at the start rather then using an algorithm to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()

    {
         cout << "Enter a  word or phrase: ";

         string originalPhrase;

         std::getline(std::cin, originalPhrase);

         // Copy the original string
         string newPhrase(originalPhrase);
         int phraseSize = originalPhrase.size();
         for(int i = 0; i < phraseSize; ++i)
         {
            // Replace each character of the string with _
            newPhrase[i] = '_';
         }

         cout << endl << "Your phrase: " << originalPhrase << endl;
         cout << endl << "Your new phrase: " << newPhrase << endl;

         cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: `std::string` also has a fill constructor that accepts a size_t and character. This would give you the same result as your for-loop: `string newPhrase(originalPhrase.length(), '_');`